# Resize canvas to path or resize path to canvas

Tags: android, canvas, path, resize

Is there a way to resize my canvas to fit the width of a path, or is there a way to resize a path to fit a canvas.

IF both are possible which would be easier and how?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    demoview = new DemoView(this); 
}

public class DemoView extends View implements OnTouchListener{

    Paint paint = new Paint();

            public DemoView(Context context){
             super(context);
            }

            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                     canvas.drawPath(Plotter.path, paint);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat artificial, but if you use your path as a clipping path you may be able to then obtain its bounds by calling getClipBounds, and from there you can easily calculate the scale transformation needed to make it resize to fit a canvas.

There's got to be a better way though.